# SQLite with Entity Framework Core is slow

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Inserting a record to SQLite DB via Entity Framework Core in C# in .NET Core is extremely slow. It is 10 times slower than my expectation. Is there a magic to improve performance?

```cs
public class MyRecord
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyDatabase : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyRecord> Records { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data source=mydb.db");
#if DEBUG
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
#endif
    }
}

public class MyDatabaseTests
{
    public MyDatabaseTests()
    {
        var db = new MyDatabase();
        db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        db.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void EntityFramework1000Transactions()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            using var db = new MyDatabase();
            var rec = new MyRecord
            {
                ID = i+1,
                Value = 123456789
            };
            var tx = db.Database.BeginTransaction();
            db.Records.Add(rec);
            db.SaveChanges();
            tx.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

`EntityFramework1000Transactions` takes 10 seconds on my PC with SATA-SSD drive. Replacing to eNVM is not my option because I am writing an application for a sort of embedded system which has equivalent storage.

I tried using `db.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`, or
`db.BulkSaveChanges();` (with Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore)

And they didn't help me.

My environment:

- Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.11.2
- .NET Core 3.1
- C#
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 5.0.11
- Windows 10

## Edit

The loop was a simulation of a process in the application. They are not single transaction. **The loop is intended to simulate 1000 transactions.** Therefore they cannot be in the same transaction.

It also cannot remove transaction. The transactions in the application is actually more complicate and can update two or more tables/records at the same time. It must be handled in a transaction. therefore removing transaction is not my option.

Comment: Add all the records once, not in a loop. Also, any reason you're constructing `MyDatabase` for every iteration, there's no need to do that. Addressing those two issue's I see will be a great performance gain.

Comment: Reuse the context, remove the transaction and save in batches rather than each individual item. It's not magic, it's just using EF Core correctly

Comment: So, probably you have to spawn threads, not just synchronous loop. I don't believe that you have 1000 threads for such task in real application. Also you don't have to start transaction, SaveChanges is doing that under hood if it cannot be executed in one SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks Svyatoslav. Our device has few threads and communicate each other. Each thread has state machine and must be safe for power cycle. I originally call single SaveChanges but I learned that DbContext can confuse when ExecuteSqlRaw is called. I also learned that creating transaction is always faster than no transaction, even if you update only one record.

Comment: It is hard to say what to do. EF adds additional overhead but, but I think, not significant in this case. Anyway test without EF, just pure SQL via SQLiteConnection and transactions. And probably SQLite can be not right database for your case.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider replacing it with something else like LevelDB.

Comment: I'd agree that this is likely an issue with the SQLite implementation or their provider. Testing this scenario with EF6 vs EF Core 3.1 for instance against SQL Server: EF6 with change tracking enabled: 13 seconds, with change tracking disabled: 7 seconds. EF Core 3.1 with change tracking enabled: 3.5 seconds, change tracking disabled: 2.2 seconds.  Explicit transaction also had an impact, but much smaller. (~5%) Opening encrypted SQLite connections is noted as being a relatively time consuming operation, if that is applicable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the number of connection hits(inside for loop) to database can resolve the problem as mentioned in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23099) thread.

Comment: While EF disposes DbConnection when DbContext is disposed, EF core keeps DbConnection. I also read an article saying DbContext should be disposed for each transition.